# Does facebook not support azure web sites?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-like, azure-web-app-service

I've added the code that has worked in the past to add a facebook "like" button to my latest site yet, although it does display the Tweet button, it does not display the facebook button.

Is it because facebook doesn't recognize and/or support azure web sites?

Here is my HTML/Javascript:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://usamaporama.azurewebsites.net" data-text="Check out this USA map with sports teams, National Parks, and hometowns of authors and musicians" data-via="BClayShannon">Tweet</a>
    <script>
        !function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top" class="fb-like" data-href="http:/usamaporama.azurewebsites.net" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui"></div>
```

### UPDATE

The Chrome Dev Tools console says: "*FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().*" but I don't grok that, as searching my code for "getLoginStatus" finds nothing, nor does searching for "FB.init".

Comment: Show us a test page. There's no reason to believe Facebook wouldn't support Azure-hosted sites without significantly more evidence than "I couldn't get the Like button to show".

Comment: It's in the code above: http://usamaporama.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I've got the same problem.  Shows in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox and Explorer.  I've even taken the page down to bare bones - FB like box only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser's JavaScript console.

> Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that; I have no idea what that means. I'm thinking maybe the second thing is more signficant. I'll update.

Comment: If you're going to be making websites, you need to learn about the JavaScript console. If there are things not working, that's likely to be where you need to look. All modern browsers have one and it's a critical webdev tool. The second thing came **from** the first thing.

Comment: Well, then, as I said, I have no idea what the application id problem is. Why would this simple web site need an App ID, anyway?